# Google Maps Geocoding API is not returning coordinates from the complete list of addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Its working fine on single address or few addresses but I am trying to read addresses from a CSV which contains 200 addresses but the program is returning only few coordinates. It also giving error index out of range when I run it without handling exception.

```
import requests
import json
import csv

apiKey = ""

with open('address.csv') as csvDataFile:
  try:
      csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
      for row in csvReader:
        # print(row)
          r = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + str(row) + "&key=" + apiKey)
          d = json.loads(r.content)
          print(d['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
  except:
          `enter code here`pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wait in your loop. There's a soft rate limit of 50 calls per second.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Comment: Added time.sleep(3) after print but still getting the same error.

Comment: What do you see if you print `d`?

Comment: print(d) contains a dictionary of results which includes address components, geometry etc. But I am slicing it for only geometry (long/lat).

Comment: I mean when you catch the exception. Try printing `r` and `d`